# Vue: getting default value for select when using objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select where I am trying to set the `:selected` value to data from my server on page load. All the data is accessible but I am not sure what I am missing. My prop `customer` is an object that is passed in from the parent and comes from the backend.  The value of `customer.state` is the abbreviated state , so `"CA"` for example.   I tried doing `:selected="this.customer.state"` but that didn't work either.

```
data() {
    return {
        this.states = [
             {text: "California", value: "CA"},
             {text: "New Jersey", value: "NJ"},
             //etc
        ],
    }
},
props: {
    customer: {type: Object}
}


<select name="state" autocomplete="address-level1" @change="optionDropdown">
    <option v-for="x in optionsReturned" :value="x.value" :selected="???">
      {{ x.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of `selected` must be true when the currently looped option is equal to customer's state (and false otherwise): `:selected="customer.state === x.value"`